# directive's template not accessing the scope when isolating it

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm trying to make a simple directive that gets an attribute and displays it from inside the directive

Here is the directive coed:

```
angular.module('JJJ')
  .directive('jobCard', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div>name: {{job}}</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:{
        job: "=j"
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

      }
    };
  });
```

html usage:

```
<job-card ng-repeat="j in jobs" job="j.name"></job-card>
```

The directive doesnt show anything. Why is that?

Comment: There is no `j` attribute on your html. Just change the `job: "=j"` to `job: "="`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

#### When you write an isolated scope like this:

```
scope: {
  job: "=j"
}
```

It means that **outer scope** variable referred with attribute `j` is set with a *two-way-data-binding* to **inner scope** variable `job`.

#### You should write it like so:

```
angular.module('JJJ')
  .directive('jobCard', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div>name: {{job}}</div>',
      scope:{
        job: "="
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: "outer scope variable j".  No, it means that the outer scope value of the attribute named `j` is mapped to the inner scope variable.

Answer (score 2):

By defining the scope variable `job` to `=j`, you are telling Angular to look for an attribute named `j`.

Isolated scope works by defining the name of the property in the isolated scope (ex `job`) and then setting that to a binding setting (ex. `=` is two-way).  In order to name the attribute you can append the name of the attribute to the end of the binding setting (ex. `=myAttribute` would look for an attribute named `myAttribute` and set the value on the directive's scope property named `job`).

```
angular.module('JJJ')
  .directive('jobCard', function () {
    return {
      template: '<div>name: {{job}}</div>',
      restrict: 'E',
      scope:{
        job: "="
      },
      link: function postLink(scope, element, attrs) {

      }
    };
  });
```

Comment: He is not using the directive as an attribute, but as an element. Therefore, the `restrict: 'E'` is correct.

Comment: @Beterraba yes, I'll adjust.

Answer (score 0):

When you want to just display a value from the outer scope (say, this directive is within controller and job is used in controller) use '@' in the directive's scope object instead of '='. As llan pointed out '=' is a two way binding which updates value in the outer scope if the value is changed inside the directive scope. In your example, for instance, changing the value of job in the link function will change the job in the outer scope (in controller) as well.